# How to switch off syntax highlight in cited code?

Tags: support, code-formatting

Suppose some code snippet that appears to be some specific syntax like C in this case, and I want to format it like plain text:

````
```
#include <code>
```
````

On stackexchange, this will be rendered as if it was C/C++ like so (on meta I'll need explicit ```` ```c ````):

```c
#include <code>
```

Is there a way to explicitly switch off any syntax highlighting here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 3):

Use the 'language' `none`:

````
```none
````

That will render your code block as

```
#include <code>
```

Alternatively, you can put `<!-- language: none -->` on a single line before the code block. That works too, but is considerably inferior since it's a lot more work to type.

Comment: Thanks.  I'v tried everything like "text", "ascii", "plain", ... but mussed "none".

Comment: Or put it in a block quote, instead of a code block :)

Comment: You can also do `<!-- language-all: none -->` to disable highlighting of all code blocks in the post. That can be helpful if you have many blocks, and/or are using indentation formatting which doesn't have any other way to specify language.